# Expanding logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Today, I was doing my math homework and while doing so I encountered a problem where I was told to expand a logarithm and simplify completely. The logarithm I was given was $log_5 1/250$. When I tried simplifying the equation I got $-log_5(250)$, so my question is do I leave as it is or do I expand even further.

Comment: If you factor $250$ into primes, you may see a further simplification for this.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. The log can be broken further down into -(lo5(125) + log5(2)), which can be simplified to -3 - log5(2). that was a silly mistake on my part for not seeing something like that.